# Server slow after Nginx errors and restarting PHP

Tags: server, php, mysql, nginx

I have a server with Intel Xeon 2xE5520 2.27GHz, 48 GB Ram, 2x146 GB 15K HDD (Raid)
OS Ubuntu 14.04.01,  Nginx 1.6.2, PHP 5.5.9, MySQL. Webmin.

My website is video portal.

Traffic is approximately 60'000 visitors/day, 110'000 pageviews/day. Today the server was beginning to show Nginx errors. After restarting PHP it runs again.

Webmin process list shows:

```
**ID             Owner           CPU         Command**   
32453   mysql   151 %   /usr/sbin/mysqld
2561    root    36.0 %  /usr/share/webmin/webmincron/webmincron.pl
1664    root    2.9 %   [cifsd]
466     www-data    1.9 %   nginx: worker process
460     www-data    1.8 %   nginx: worker process
463     www-data    1.7 %   nginx: worker process
459     www-data    1.6 %   nginx: worker process
464     www-data    1.4 %   nginx: worker process
462     www-data    1.3 %   nginx: worker process
2462    www-data    0.7 %   php-fpm: pool www
2254    www-data    0.6 %   php-fpm: pool www
2256    www-data    0.6 %   php-fpm: pool www
2431    www-data    0.5 %   php-fpm: pool www
2460    www-data    0.5 %   php-fpm: pool www
2255    www-data    0.4 %   php-fpm: pool www
2258    www-data    0.4 %   php-fpm: pool www
2259    www-data    0.4 %   php-fpm: pool www
2433    www-data    0.4 %   php-fpm: pool www
2253    www-data    0.3 %   php-fpm: pool www
2257    www-data    0.3 %   php-fpm: pool www
2260    www-data    0.3 %   php-fpm: pool www 
2261    www-data    0.3 %   php-fpm: pool www
2429    www-data    0.3 %   php-fpm: pool www
```

I have modified `my.cnf` file raised cache sizes. I have modified `etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` :

```
pm.max_children = 300
pm.start_servers = 9
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 16
pm.max_requests = 10000
```

It stopped to **showing** Nginx errors, but now the website is very slow. Webmin shows CPU usage    5% user, 2% kernel, 25% IO, 68% idle

The video files are on another machine. I have one addition server and can use it for MySQL server to standalone. Would that help? What would you suggest to do?

Ask if any additional info or screen shots is needed.
Nginx error screenshot:
http://www.vitube.ge/nginxerror.jpg

thanks

Comment: What exactly is the error? What is your question?

Comment: server is slowing down and what I have to do with that ?

Comment: The Nginx error messages would have been nice to know. What kind of Nginx error were they? Could add them to your question text? You can edit your question when you click the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/544518/edit) below your question.

Comment: I have added error screenshot image link

Comment: At those specs i would assume the issue is because of php-fpm, try getting APC if you do not have it, and increase memory limit in the php.ini file.

Comment: Thanks for comment, what do you mean in APC?

Comment: Is the mysql with 151 % load usual?